# Connection from Databricks to Snowflake

Tags: jdbc, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Databricks notebook, I am able to connect to 'snowflake' from Databricks and write content to a table in Snowflake using 'scala' but it doesn't work using 'python'.

I have added both libraries in Databricks which helps to establish the connection between Databricks and Snowflake:
`snowflake-jdbc-3.6.8` and `spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.4-spark_2.2`.

My goal is to use Databricks(for machine learning - Spark) and move data back and forth between Databricks and Snowflake.

Here is the code, where I am trying to write the content of the DataFrame to Snowflake:

1. Load data into DataFrame

```
    df1 = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true")\
               .option("inferSchema", "true")\
               .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00000")
    display(df1)
```

I can see data has been loaded into dataframe.

2. Use secret manager to get the login name and password for the Snowflake user.

```
    user = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="jdbc", key="snowflake_username")
    password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="jdbc", key="snowflake_password")
```

3. Snowflake connection options:

```
    options = dict(sfUrl="https://***snowflake_username***.snowflakecomputing.com",
                   sfUser=user,
                   sfPassword=password,
                   sfDatabase="my_database",
                   sfSchema="PUBLIC",
                   sfWarehouse="my_warehouse")

    SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
```

No errors so far

4. Write contents of the DataFrame to Snowflake

```
    df1.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
        .options(**options) \
        .option("dbtable", "datafromspark") \
          .save()
```

That causes:

```
**Error : 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:snowflake://https://*snowflake_username*.snowflakecomputing.com**
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the error:

In step 3 there is no need to mention `"https://"`

i.e.

```
sfUrl="https://snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"   # giving an error

sfUrl="snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"          #works fine
```

Comment: sfUrl="https://snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"

I tried below possibilities:
1. Removed "https://" from sfUrl and tried with sfUrl="snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"

2. Added "jdbc:snowflake" and tried as sfUrl="jdbc:snowflake://https://snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"

3. Removed "https://" and added "jdbc:snowflake" and tried with sfUrl="jdbc:snowflake://snowflake_username.snowflakecomputing.com"

In all the cases I am getting the ame error.

Comment: @Ktn Patel - Could you please share the entire code snippet as trying to do the same in Python and new to SnowFlake? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I also get the same issue... thx for sharing

Answer (score 0):

This actually works fine (considering user is allowed to write to schema and read from it later)

```
import dbutils

# Use secrets DBUtil to get Snowflake credentials.
user = dbutils.secrets.get("snowflake", "xx")
password = dbutils.secrets.get("snowflake", "xy")

# snowflake connection options
options = {
    "sfUrl": "XXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfUser": user,
    "sfPassword": password,
    "sfDatabase": "DBX_TEST",
    "sfSchema": "DBX_SCHEMA"
}

# write the dataset to Snowflake
# sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(...)
sparkDF.write.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("dbtable", "name_table").save()

# Connect to Snowflake and build data frame
df = spark.read.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake") \
    .options(**options) \
    .option("query", "select * from name_table") \
    .load()
```